# Finding an explicit homotopy to prove inverses exist in fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The problem statement is: Suppose $X$ is a topological space with base point $x$. Let $\gamma_0:I\to X$ be the constant map $\gamma_0(s)=x, \forall s\in I$. Suppose $\gamma:I\to X$ is a continuous map with $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=x$. Define $\tilde{\gamma}:I\to X$ by $\tilde{\gamma(s)}:=\gamma(1-s)$.

Now I am trying to find a explicit based homotopy $\{f_t: I\to X\}_{t\in I}$ between $\tilde{\gamma}*\gamma$ and $\gamma_0$. I would like some help for getting started, a picture will be extremely helpful because I can't see what is going on.

Comment: Hint 1: only $f_t(0)$ and $f_t(1)$ are required to stay at $x$. Although $f_0(1/2) = (\tilde{\gamma}*\gamma)(1/2) = x$ as well, $f_t(1/2)$ need not equal $x$ for $t > 0$.  Hint 2: for any $s \in [0,1]$, you already know a curve connecting $x$ and $\gamma(s)$.

Comment: A homotopy is a family of curves. You can imagine this homotopy by picturing the family as follows: first you go through all of $\gamma$ and then back, then you go through almost all of $\gamma$ and go back, and you keep doing this continuously until eventually you're not going through $\gamma$ at all, and that's the constant path.

Answer (score 0):

As you ask for a picture, here is one taken from [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html).

[image: inv]

Note that this account deals with paths as maps $a:[0,r] \to X$ where $r \geqslant 0$, which is called a "path of length $r$". Thus if a path $b$ in $X$ is of length $s \geqslant 0$ and their composite $a+b$ is defined then that is of length $r+s$.  This makes the exposition easier; addition of such paths yields a category, in particular associativity holds. Also this does not restrict to loops at a base point.

Comment: A detailed discussion of the diagram and how it's constructed would be very helpful here. Yes, I know, the response is usually, "It's just analytic geometry from high school! Are you stupid?" No, just weak in visual geometry and for a lot of us, it's hard to connect what we know about analytic geometry to this diagram. Of course, once we're taken through it, we wonder why we didn't see something so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explicit homotopy from $\bar{\gamma}\ast \gamma$ to $\gamma_0$:
$$
F(s,t) = \left\{\begin{array}[cc]
  \gamma\gamma(2s) & s\in [0, \frac{1}{2}(1-t)]\\
\gamma\left(\frac{2(1-t)}{1+t}(1-s)\right) & s\in [\frac{1}{2}(1-t),1]
\end{array}\right.
$$
Note at $s=\frac{1}{2}(1-t)$, the top curve and the bottom curve both give $\gamma(1-s)$.  Hence, $F$ is continuous.  Also, $F(s,0)=\bar{\gamma}\ast \gamma(s)$ and $F(s,1)=\gamma(0)=x$.  Hence, $F(s,1)=\gamma_0(s)$.